# How use form select in cake php with foreach

Tags: cakephp-2.x

I want to fill  a form select with informations of a table :"foreach"
i don't find a solution , someone can help me !i use cakephp 2.5.5 .
i want solution like that , but with cake php .

```
  <select id="Select" name="section_id" class="form-control">
    @foreach($sections as  $section)

    <option value="{{$section->id}}">{{$section->section_name}}</option>
    @endforeach
  </select>
```

Comment: Explain properly. what  should you want?

Comment: @Tony stark i want to fill a form select from a table in data base!

Comment: means you want to auto fill database saved data in select box?

Comment: @Tony stark yea i mean the same , i hape u can help me ! thanx )

Answer (score 0):

Try this
First fetch data from database  like this :

```
$result = $this->ModelName->findById('id');
$this->set('result',$result);
```

Then check in view file

```
<select id="Select" name="section_id" class="form-control">
@foreach($sections as  $section)

<option <?php echo ($result['ModelName']['section_id'] == $section->id) ? 'selected="selected"' : '' ?> value="{{$section->id}}">{{$section->section_name}}</option>
@endforeach
</select>
```

Use Cakephp form helper to create select box so cake automatic display selected data like this

```
$this->From->select('ModelName.select_box_name',$sections);
```

Comment: the problem cake php do not accept the type of select , so my problem it is the syntax of select " with the select above i can't insert value  to database ")  !!

Comment: i find a solution :    $en_attente= $this->User->find('list', array(
        'fields' => array('User.username'),
        'conditions' => array('User.role' => 'respensable'),
        'recursive' => 0
    ));
         $this->set('users',$en_attente);  , thanx for ur help ))